# Remap Home and End Keys to beginning and end of line in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remap “Home” and “End” to beginning and end of line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line)

I've recently gotten a mac and during my coding sessions, I'm really missing the usage of home/end to go to the front/end of each line.  There are various answers to this which talk about creating a .dict file in the Library folder (eg the below) but these don't seem to work in Mountain Lion.

Would someone mind confirming if this should be working, or whether a new method is needed in the new OS?

[Remap "Home" and "End" to beginning and end of line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line)

I can't tell if I'm performing the fix incorrectly or the older answer no longer applies on Mountain Lion.

Comment: You are not using `Cmd + left arrow` for Home and `Cmd + right arrow` for End?

Comment: Hi Hoshts.  No, I am constantly toggling between development environments in win and osx, and would like to make the hotkeys consistent.  I've actually found that QuicKeys does the trick nicely - but it's $60 which is a lot for the couple of basic fixes I need.

Comment: It should still work on 10.8. Did you quit and reopen applications after saving the property list? DefaultKeyBinding.dict is ignored by Xcode, Terminal, and many cross-platform applications.