# Trouble opening plist files in text editor

Tags: macos, plist, xml

From Finder, I can preview a plist file without any difficulties. For example, using Quick Look with `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.RSS.plist` I get a nice preview of its contents:

[image: Quick Look]

However, if I then try to open the file, either with TextEdit, or any other editor (I've tried SublimeText, TextMate, Vim, Nano, and Coda 2 so far), the encoding appears to be off:

```
bplist00Ò_"FixedRefreshesInBackgroundSettings_(com.apple.PreferenceSync.ExcludeSyncKeys ¡ 2]^����������������������������`
```

Here's what it looks like if I open it with TextEdit:

[image: TextEdit]

I've tried changing the encoding in Sublime Text and other apps, but that doesn't help.

Any thoughts?

I'm running 10.8.4.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

plist files are not necessarily plain text so they need to be run through a converter. Finder and Xcode (which has a plist editor) do this without telling the user

The binary format is documented in this [C code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBinaryPList.c) so any application can convert it and [someone has written a format description in English](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Property_List/Binary) and more Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) but note that it references old paths in `/Developer/Documentation`

The command line program [plutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/plutil) can convert to and from XML

e.g. to view a binary property list in XML format on stdout:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o - <file name>
```

Also to convert a binary to a XML plist in place and then leave it so that the user program can read either.

```
plutil -convert xml1 <file name>
```

Comment: Thanks. I see. So if I need to edit it, I need to convert it to XML, open it with an editor, and then convert it back. I will assume this is so. No need to reply unless I got it wrong!

Comment: You can also use `plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.RSS.plist` to convert the plist to XML in place. And after you edit the plist, you don't have to convert it back to binary.

Comment: > Finder and Xcode (which has a plist editor) do this without telling the user
To be precise, it’s not Finder that’s doing this, it’s QuickLook in the form of a QuickLook plugin.

Comment: You can also use the newer `defaults read <file>` command to get a kind of JSON view of it.

Answer (score 6):

You can also edit plist files with [PlistBuddy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html), which is a command-line program.

PlistBuddy is located at `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`.

Comment: Apple removed that page, and I can’t find any archive. Manual still available on macOS Mojave though.

Comment: @FranklinYu, indeed. There is also  tutorial at https://marcosantadev.com/manage-plist-files-plistbuddy/.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned Sublime Text, there is now a plugin you can use which automatically does the conversion for you:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BinaryPlist

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit will convert binary plists and then save them correctly on-the-fly.

Answer (score -2):

You can convert the property list file from binary format into XML using the following command line:

```
plutil -convert xml1 -o file.plist file.plist
```

Then edit it as usual. Secondly you don't have to convert it back, as usually apps recognise both formats.