# CMD + arrow goes to beginning of line , conflicts with Sublime

Tags: macos, keyboard, sublimetext

I am trying to use cmd+left/right to do "focus to group" in Sublime, but my cursor goes to the beginning/end of line instead.

Note that I'm using a PC keyboard.. and I've remapped the modifiers (Super=CMD,CTRL=CMD).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Command </kbd>  +  <kbd>Arrow</kbd>  is the system standard for 'beginning/end of line'.

This gives a good way to remap key bindings... [Remap "Home" and "End" to beginning and end of line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line?rq=1)