# Does ctrl-A and ctrl-E on a mac work the same as HOME and END on Windows?

Tags: keyboard

Coming from a Windows Machine to a Mac - one of the things I missed was the HOME and END keys when editing a text document.

Then I discovered:

```
ctrl-E # move cursor to end of line
ctrl-A # move cursor to beginning of line
```

Which seems to do the same thing.

I'm wondering if this making too much of an assumption or I'm missing something. Although I've tested it, I'm asking the question because there might be a different scenario I've missed that makes it different.

My question is: **Does ctrl-A and ctrl-E on a mac work the same as HOME and END on Windows?**

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line?rq=1

Comment: When I switched from Windows to OS X there were a few key combinations that I missed; plus as I had bought a Mac mini I was still using my favorite Windows keyboard. I found the Mac app Karabiner to be extremely useful to remap keys for functions I was familiar with. See: [link]https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this convention is coming from the Emacs text editor on Unix.
Windows copied it 30 years later :).

Of course, this is working in:

```
emacs
```

and these 2 shells which inherited the editing line shortcuts of `emacs`:

```
bash
zsh
```

and these Apple graphical interface software:

```
Calendar
Messages
Notes
TextEdit
LibreOffice
Pages
Finder
```

On the other hand, this convention is failing in:

```
vi
```

and I suspect in some other softwares which have their own set of shortcuts without enough freedom to keep these very old and useful ones.

Comment: They copied a lot didn't they...

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes, at least in TextWrangler and TextEdit :)