# How do I do Home and End in iterm2?

Tags: iterm, keybindings

`Home` and `End` do nothing in iTerm2, nor do ⌘← and ⌘→.

However, Ctrl-`A` and Ctrl-`E` do work.

Can `Home` and `End` do this?

*Preferences->Keys_Key Bindings* in iTerm2 do not offer a "Start of Line" or  "End of Line option.

Related: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/585518/how-to-make-commandarrow-go-to-begining-and-end-of-line-in-iterm2), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm-2-how-to-set-keyboard-shortcuts-to-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm-2-how-to-set-keyboard-shortcuts-to-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line

Answer (score 73, accepted):

<kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> are keybinding in Bash and ZSH, not in iTerm (or Terminal).

If you want custom bindings within iTerm, you will need to bind the actual keyboard sequence in the keybinding.  "Start of Line" and "End of Line" are descriptors, not the actual key strokes.

So, to do this you'd need to send <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> for <kbd>Home</kbd> via their [Hex Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes).  In this case, the codes would be `0x01` for "start of text" (^A) and `0x05` for "ENQ" (^E).

In the image below, you can add a new binding in *Preferences → Keys → Key Bindings*

1. Click on `+` to add a new binding
2. Click on Record in the dialog box
3. Press your desired key (<kbd>Home</kbd> in this case).
4. Select your Action (you can scroll or search).  Select "Send Hex Code"
5. Enter the Hex Code (0x01 for "start of text")
6. Test it out!

[image: iTerm2 Keybinding Home to ^A]

Comment: Note:  I'm trying to add some screen shots, but my Dell 104 key  keyboard with the Home/End/PgUp/PgDn etc. buttons seems to have developed legs and a passion for ice cream as it apparently left the house.  As soon as I get my keyboard back, I'll get some screen shots going.

Comment: Thank you! One correction: 0x05 is End, while 0x03 that you gave is Ctl-C (break out of the line.)

Comment: This answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920414 since it works for VIM as well.

Answer (score 57):

The accepted solution proposed by [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan) is not optimal, as this keybinding affects *ALL* applications that are executed on the terminal and this key remapping would mean that some applications won't work as expected:

For example, if you use '**vi**' then the keys '**Home**' and '**End**' no longer work after this key binding (those keys work ok if you don't do the proposed key binding)

A better solution is to do the key mapping on the shell itself:

In zsh (the default shell being used by macos nowadays), just add this in **~/.zshrc**:

```
bindkey '\e[H'    beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[F'    end-of-line
```

and **Home** and **End** keys will work ok in both the command line and **vi**

Comment: This is the optimal solution!

Comment: While you said about remaping for all apps is true the bindings you have provided does not work.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution!

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\e[D` for beginning of line? Atleast in my iTerm, pressing Option and CursorLeft seem to produce escape-D

Comment: This is "the optimal solution" since it doesn't do anything for remote servers, Docker containers, etc. without modifying files there. The reason I use iTerm is for its ability to use custom settings wherever I go. This answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920414

Answer (score 5):

For me the best answer was a combination of the above:

1. **Preferences->Keys**: Remove the default key bindings in iterm for `Home` and `End`. This will cause `Home` (`fn`+`left arrow` in mac) & `End` (`fn`+`right arrow` in mac) to work normally as in linux and not as `Scroll to Top` or `Scroll to Bottom` respectively.
2. **Preferences->Profiles->Keys**: Make sure that the box for "Page up, page down, home and end..." is not checked.

This allows to jump to start or end of line in all cases using `Home` & `End` keys, including in '**vi**'

Comment: I may be missing something, but this doesn't quite work. I don't have "the default key bindings" you mention, ie. they're already "removed". This was the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920414 that works at the CLI and in Vim.