# How do I get Home and End working for BOTH iTerm2 and VIM?

Tags: mac, keyboard, iterm

I have been through at least a dozen articles and internet searches (including [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389525/how-do-i-do-home-and-end-in-iterm2)) and I cannot find a setting that satisfies what I want:  Both iTerm2 (at command prompt) and VIM to recognize Home and End the way they're meant to be used.

If I set Home to hex code `0x01` in iTerm2 key mapping, it starts working at the prompt, but stops working in VIM.

If I leave it alone, hitting Home and End work fine in VIM, but not at prompt.

What the hell is going on?

I have a Mac Keybinds file (located at `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`) that looks like this; and I have the same behavior when the keyword is `BeginningOfLine` as what's set here (`BeginningOfParagraph`):

```
{
/* Home Button*/
"\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfParagraph:";

/* End Button */
"\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfParagraph:";

/* Shift + Home Button */
"$\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfParagraphAndModifySelection:";

/* Shift + End Button */
"$\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfParagraphAndModifySelection:";

/* Ctrl + Home Button */
"^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";

/* Ctrl + End Button */
"^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:";

/* Shift + Ctrl + Home Button */
"$^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocumentAndModifySelection:";

/* Shift + Ctrl + End Button*/
"$^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocumentAndModifySelection:";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem turned out to be Zshell.

New macbooks come default with zshell now, creating confusion for setting these keys on a full size keyboard.  Typing `bash` and using that as my default shell worked without a problem, but I wanted to know how to accomplish this in zshell.

The solution was to first remove any keybindings set in iTerm for home and end; then modify `~/.zshrc` with the following I got from [this link](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets):

```
bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line
```

Then, obviously, `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: you might wanna add, that first we need to remove the home and key bindings from iterm2 key preferences, and then set the values in ~/.zshrc as you said.

Comment: how do you know the "^[[H" is for Home and "^[[F" is for End? where i can found the reference table for each key? This solution worked fine, thx!

Comment: Hey @ArthurMelo, the link is right there in my post.