# How do I remap Home/End key behaviour in Java Swing applications?

Tags: macos, keyboard, java, keybindings

I am using a Java Swing applications as a code editor. I find it hugely annoying that the Home and End keys behave differently on macOS than the rest of the world. Under macOS they go start and end of document instead of start and end of line. Is there a convenient way of fixing this, for instance by setting an AWT/Swing property on the command line, without diving into Java code?

I have already added a `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` rebind file as described in [Remap “Home” and “End” to beginning and end of line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16137/328685), but that has no effect though it does work on TextEdit. I forget and it is inconvenient to use ⌘← or ⌃A for Home and ⌘→ or ⌃E for end.